# Android View Not Appearing

Tags: android, visibility

I am attempting to have a new view appear on top of my main view.

Here is the XML for the new view:

```
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/mapdetaillayout" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        android:gravity="left"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

             <TextView 
                android:text="This is the Text from the XML File." 
                android:id="@+id/DetailTextView" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the code I am using to push the new viev onto the screen:

```
        RelativeLayout DetailLayout = new RelativeLayout(c);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapdetailview, DetailLayout);    

        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.DetailTextView);
        tv.setText("HERE IS THE TEXT FROM THE CODE");

        // This Log works
        Log.i("MESSAGE", tv.getText());

        DetailLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;

        DetailLayout.bringToFront();
        DetailLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

The code is getting called and the Log outputs the expected text, which to me indicates that the View has been created - it just isn's being displayed on the screen.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see any call to Activity's setContentView() method in your code. Probably you just do not do that? If so, that's the reason why you do not see anything. Also you do not need to instantinate RelativeLayout manually. Try just to specify layout resource as content view:

```
setContentView(R.layout.mapdetailview);
```

You can then get your TextView just by:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DetailTextView);
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Why you're doing that? Looks like something completely wrong for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT to fill_parent to see if anything changes?